# apex:pageBlockButtons issue: Can't 'remove' both top and bottom buttons, only the upper one is removed

Tags: visualforce

I created a button within a pageBlockButtons component and set its 'Location' attribute to 'both'.

I have a JS method which "removes" this button from the Block by changing its CSS attributes. It works, but only with the top button, the bottom one remains. If the Location attribute is set to both why does it only hide the one at the top?

```
<apex:page controller="controller1">
    <apex:form id="formId">
        <apex:pageBlock title="" mode="edit">

            <apex:pageBlockButtons title="" location="both">

                <button id="assistButtonOnline">Get Assistance</button>

            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var online = '{!isOnline}';
            if (online == 'false') {
                document.getElementById("assistButtonOnline").style.display = "none";
                console.log('assistButtonOnline was removed');
            } 
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the Location attribute is set to both why does it only hide the one at the top?

Because document.getElementById returns only one element (the first on the page that matches).

Instead, you would need to use querySelectorAll, as in:

```
if(online == 'false') {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id=assistButtonOnline]'),
      function(element) { element.style.display = 'none'; }
  );
}
```